# Date and time from PHP writes 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a PHP with a JS datepicker for date and time that save all the string in this format "19.08.2012 @ 20:18" in a a variable called $date.

If I place this variable directly in the query, it writes "0000-00-00 00:00:00" in the database.
At the moment I have a big black hole in my head, so need help.

How can I write the correct selected date and time in the database?

---

Sorry I thought not so important, here is the code.

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#date").datetimepicker({
        dateFormat:'dd.mm.yy',
        separator: ' @ '
    });
});
</script>

<form action="setting.php" method="post">
 <table>
 <tr>
  <td><label for="date">Date:</label></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="date" name="date"/></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
```

setting.php

```
if(isset($_POST['save_autoresp'])) {
    create($_POST['date']);
    header("Location: admin.php");
    exit();
} else {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
```

functions.php

```
.......
.......
// Write the fields to the table
$query_create = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO table VALUES (null, '$id', '$date')") or die ('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($link));
.......
.......
```

The date field in teh MySQL database is "datetime".

Comment: Can you share some source code with us ?

Comment: I have a hunch what the problem might be, but cannot say so for sure if you do not give us the source code.. If you submit the function itself to the database (before it has calculated) and you do so between, say apostrephes ('') it will try to submit a variable that is not datetime, and therefore simply submits a 0 datetime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The date you receive is in a format that MySQL doesn't recognize. You must first transform it into an [accepted date and time literal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-literals.html), then you can pass it to the INSERT.

This conversion can be done in two ways:

- You can configure your JS DateTime Picker so that it returns a date as "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS".
- You can do the above conversion in PHP.

Whichever you'll choose, stick to the Year-Month-Day format for the dates when saving to the database, so that you won't get crazy in finding out why "08/02" was considered the 2nd of August instead of the 8th of February.

Comment: I found the problem, it was the @ in the string. I removed it and everything works great now. Always stupid errors :P
Thanks for the help.

Comment: This helps. the actual format in php I had to use was 'Y-m-d H:i:s'.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to convert your variable to specify the correct format for MySQL, being YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS. That's all. Accomplish by throwing sone substring functions at it.

Comment: I found the problem, it was the @ in the string. I removed it and everything works great now. Always stupid errors :P
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you write the string "19.08.2012 @ 20:18" directly in a query, MySQL simply cannot parse it. You have to convert it first, depending on the field (column) which either is INT, TIMESTAMP, or DATETIME.

MySQL comes with some handy [date calculation functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html), so you should stick to DATETIME.

In PHP you can convert it using `gmmktime()` and `gmdate()`. To make your own life easier, make sure the MySQL server is running at UTC and your application converts dates to UTC before inserting it to MySQL.

When fetching the dates for output, simply use proper `date_default_timezone_set()`.

Comment: I found the problem, it was the @ in the string. I removed it and everything works great now. Always stupid errors :P
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

you need to convert the date to mysql date format 
you can use explode() function to remove the '.' sign from your date first and then use the mktime() function to make a mysql date format

```
$date = exolode('.', $_POST['date']);
$unixtime= mktime(0, 0, 0, $date[1], $date[0], $date[2]);
$date1 = date("H-m-d H:i:s", $unixtime);
$final_Date = strtotime($date1);
```